# Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3, local-storage

I was trying to set `UNIX` time in local storage by:

```
let dt: number = Date.now();
localStorage.setItem('logged', dt+864000000);
```

> **Returning with error:** Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'string'

It's giving the same error when i use `getItem` to read the `logged` data.

Any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try this

```
let dt: number = Date.now();
localStorage.setItem('logged', ""+dt+864000000);
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: `let logged: number = localStorage.getItem('logged');` returns `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

Comment: use this `let logged: number = Number(localStorage.getItem('logged'));`

Comment: glad that it helps you 
, please tick the answer for more convenience of users

Answer (score 7):

All items in local storage are **strings**. You're trying to pass a number in as the second argument to `setItem` when `setItem`'s second paramter is type `string`, so naturally TypeScript warns you (because you've asked for type safety) that you can't do that.

If you want to store in local storage, explicitly turn it into a string:

```
let dt: number = Date.now();
localStorage.setItem('logged', String(dt+864000000));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is also correct for the first problem but unfortunately I can mark only one answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
let dt = Date.now();
localStorage.setItem('logged', dt+864000000);
```

And when `localStorage.getItem('logged')`

```
"1514712216523"
```